# Is it possible to make an application that docks to the top of screen?

Tags: c, vb.net, visual-studio

Using (I think) Visual basic / studio I want to make a bar to go at the top of my screen which would display a webpage.

Before I start trying to code it, is this concept possible (that the bar would dock at the top of the screen and other windows would change to fit around it.)

Thanks - Ryan

Comment: I believe the Magnifier does something like this, at least on Vista. If you want the same behavior then that might help you find out how.

Comment: Yes it is in this same design, will look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you would probably need to create it as a Windows Shell plugin.